Error while running "docker compose pull" in Apache Superset
Following the steps provided in this guide while installing Apache Superset on Windows,
I've had errors while setting up a docker container using Docker Compose (after cloning the project in apache/superset).
docker compose pull
and
docker compose up -d
gives me:
time="2024-04-20T21:18:08-03:00" level=warning msg="The \"CYPRESS_CONFIG\" variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank string."
time="2024-04-20T21:18:08-03:00" level=warning msg="The \"SCARF_ANALYTICS\" variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank string."
time="2024-04-20T21:18:08-03:00" level=warning msg="The \"CYPRESS_CONFIG\" variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank string."
validating C:\superset\superset\docker-compose.yml: services.superset.env_file.0 must be a string

I don't know how to fix this error, since it says it can't find the environment variables and it can't read properly the env file. I have searched in the whole internet, github discussions and stackoverflow but had zero success.

Update your docker version to latest(on windows update docker desktop), because you are using compose plugin. Compose also will be updated to ~ v2.26.X. This is a latest feature of docker compose 2.24.
Added to superset here: https://github.com/apache/superset/pull/28039

validating C:\superset\superset\docker-compose.yml: services.superset.env_file.0 must be string
env_file:
             # defaults
             - docker/.env
             # gitignored overrides
             - docker/.env-local

//replace all env_file in dockercompose file above by :
 env_file: docker/.env


This is a great workaraound if for whatever reason one needs to run docker on Mac/Big Sur. Upgrading docker is not possible in that environment since  24.* is the last docker version supporting for Big Sur.

Starting to symphatize with the Japanese whaling fleet.

Modify your C:\superset\superset\docker-compose.yml file and add following lines to yml file under services :
env_file:
  - path: docker/.env # default
    required: true
  - path: docker/.env-local # optional override
    required: false

For others two variables set them in docker-compose.yml file as true/false depending upon your requirements.

Currently these are already the values in docker-compose

docker version incompatibility. The Superset is the good boy here, docker is the bad. Let's assume you can't upgrade the whale-tool. Only solution here is to replace
`env_file:

path: docker/.env # default
required: true
path: docker/.env-local # optional override
required: false`

to
env_file: docker/.env
Sorry about it.

For MacOS: Upgrade the docker version in your machine.
Below process might be helpful:
macOS:
How to Upgrade Docker to the Latest Version
Open Docker Desktop:
Ensure that Docker Desktop is running on your macOS. You can find Docker in the Applications folder or via Spotlight search.
Check for Updates:
Click the Docker icon in the menu bar at the top of your screen.
Select Check for Updates from the dropdown menu.
If an update is available, follow the prompts to download and install it.
Manual Update (if necessary):
If the automatic update does not work or you prefer a manual update:
Visit the official Docker Desktop for Mac download page.
Download the latest version of Docker Desktop for Mac.
Open the downloaded .dmg file and drag the Docker icon to the Applications folder, replacing the old version.
Verify the Update:
After the update is complete, open a terminal and run:
docker --version
This command will display the current version of Docker installed on your machine, ensuring the update was successful.
By following these steps, you can easily keep Docker up to date on your macOS, ensuring you have the latest features and security improvements.

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
